Delayed Data Ingestion from Cloud Storage to Datastore: How Long Should It Take?
I've set up automatic data ingestion from a Cloud Storage bucket to a Datastore following the instructions in the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-es#storage-periodic-sync). However, I'm experiencing some issues and would appreciate your insights:

Expected vs. Actual Ingestion Time:

I set up the ingestion yesterday, but as of today, no txt files have been imported as documents in the Datastore.
What's the typical timeframe for this process to complete?

In the documentation, the default is 1 hour, but this was not the case.

After you set up your data source and import data the first time, data is synced from that source at a frequency that you select during setup. About an hour after the data connector is created, the first sync occurs.


Is there a way to check the progress or status of the ingestion?

Connector state is Active.




Troubleshooting Steps:

Are there any common issues that might cause delays in ingestion?
What logs or metrics should I check to diagnose potential problems?


Configuration Verification:

How can I verify that my ingestion setup is correct?
Are there any specific permissions or settings that are often overlooked?



In the documentation, it is specified that data cannot be manually refreshed.




Hi @Pedro P. Camellon, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
